# Rescuing error does nothing?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, exception, mailchimp

I'm trying to rescue an exception with this method:

```
def template_deleted
  mailchimp_client.templates.info(mailchimp_id)
rescue Mailchimp::InvalidTemplateError => error
  puts "Template deleted in Mailchimp: #{error}"
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

And no matter what I use to output the message, whether it's `STDERR`, `STDOUT`, `log.error`, `p`, `puts`, or `print`, nothing gets out to the environment's log. This should definitely be returning an error, because the template definitely doesn't exist in Mailchimp.

When I try the same code in the console I can read the error just fine, so either there's something wrong with the rescuing itself (i.e., my method is returning `false` which it shouldn't), or there's something wrong with the way I'm outputting it.

Comment: You are not clear. Are you getting the output in the console, but want to direct that to a log instead?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: Did you try to use `logger.debug` instead of just `puts`?

Comment: Perhaps the exception that is being thrown is not the one you're expecting. To check the class of the exception, use this model: `begin 1/0 ; rescue Exception => error ; puts error.class end`

Comment: @peak Yeah, that looks usefull, I'll try that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output something in the log file of the current environment, use the [Rails logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#sending-messages) like this:

```
logger.debug "Template deleted in Mailchimp: #{error}"
```

You can replace the `debug` method call with any logging level name, that are briefly described in the link above. Also don't forget to make sure you're running in correct environment!

Comment: Yeah, that gives me nothing too.

Comment: @CD-RUM you need to read the link in the answer, because you may need to change the log level. Also, make sure you're looking at the correct of the environment that's currently running.

Comment: Whoa, not what I was expecting. It returned `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'logger' for class Whatever`.

Comment: `loggger` is only present in the Rails scope. If you are trying this on a PORO class, you're doing it the wrong way. You can also access it with `Rails.logger.debug`